# Using url key as the only url of product

Tags: magento-1.7

In `Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Url.php`, at the end of function  `getUrl`, I added:

```
/// Added
if($product->getUrlKey()) {
    $routeParams['_direct'] = $product->getUrlKey();
}
///

return $this->getUrlInstance()->setStore($storeId)
            ->getUrl($routePath, $routeParams);
```

In `eav_attribute` table, I've set `url_key` to unique, so editors won't accidentally set same key for multiple products.

And it works, all products have simple url (http://example.com/some-url-key), canonical urls are correct, links in catalog, cart e.t.c. are correct.

I can't find any flaws of this, is it really that simple? **Do you know any issues that can appear because of such change?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution to include only product key in url is to configure the settings as:

```
System > Configuration > Catalog > Search Engine Optimization > Use Categories Path for Product URLs = No
```

Comment: For some reason it didn't work for me. At the end of url_key there was always random 2-4 numbers, not sure why, though.

Comment: that means you have duplicate url_keys. Try to find out and fix it. In worst case you can truncate core_url_rewrite table and reindex. (Be sure to check if you have any custom url redirects before truncating the table)